# verilog error ... (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net array

Tags: verilog

Using Verilog, I want to make 4by4 multiplier, but there is one error:

> vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net array "w11".

about other variables w12, o1..... there is also error...

I cannot understand the meaning of the error.  If you can solve this error, please tell me.

```
module half_adder (x,y,s,c);
  input x,y;
  output s,c;

  assign s=x^y;
  assign c=x&y;   
endmodule

module full_adder (x,y,z,s,c);
  input x,y,z;
  output s,c;
  wire w1,w2,w3;

  half_adder h1(x,y,w1,w2);
  half_adder h2(w1,z,s,w3);
  assign c = w2|w3;
endmodule   

module  four_bit_adder (a, b, c0, s, c4);
  input [3:0]a;
  input [3:0]b;
  input c0;
  output [3:0]s;
  output c4;
  wire c1,c2,c3;

  full_adder fu1(a[0],b[0],c0,s[0],c1);
  full_adder fu2(a[1],b[1],c1,s[1],c2);
    
  full_adder fu3(a[2],b[2],c2,s[2],c3);
  full_adder fu4(a[3],b[3],c3,s[3],c4);
endmodule
```

maybe there is error next code

```
// 4by4_multiplier
module four_four_multi (A,B, zero, C);
  input [3:0]A;
  input [3:0]B;
  input zero;
  output [7:0]C;
  wire w11[3:0];
  wire w12[3:0];
  wire o1[3:0];
  wire w21[3:0];
  wire w22[3:0];
  wire o2[3:0];
  wire w31[3:0];
  wire w32[3:0];
  wire o3[3:0];
  wire o4;
  
  assign C[0] = A[0] & B[0];

  assign w11[0] = A[0] & B[1];
  assign w11[1] = A[0] & B[2];
  assign w11[2] = A[0] & B[3];
  assign w11[3] = 0;
  
  assign w12[0] = A[1] & B[0];
  assign w12[1] = A[1] & B[1];
  assign w12[2] = A[1] & B[2];
  assign w12[3] = A[1] & B[3];

  four_bit_adder four1(w11, w12, zero, o1 ,w21[3] );

  assign C[1] = o1[0];
  assign w21[0] = o1[1];
  assign w21[1] = o1[2];
  assign w21[2] = o1[3];
  
  assign w22[0] = A[2] & B[0];
  assign w22[1] = A[2] & B[1];
  assign w22[2] = A[2] & B[2];
  assign w22[3] = A[2] & B[3];

  four_bit_adder four2(w21, w22, zero, o2 ,w31[3] );

  assign C[2] = o2[0];
  assign w31[0] = o2[1];
  assign w31[1] = o2[2];
  assign w31[2] = o2[3];
  
  four_bit_adder four3(w31, w32, zero, o3 , o4 );

  assign C[3] = o3[0];
  assign C[4] = o3[1];
  assign C[5] = o3[2];
  assign C[6] = o3[3];
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The following declaration declares nets w11, w12, ... as arrays of nets.

```
  wire w11[3:0];
  wire w12[3:0];
  ...
```

The **verilog** standard allows you to declare them but does not allow using them as whole  array in ports. To fix it in verilog you need to declare those nets as vectors:

```
  wire [3:0] w11;
  wire [3:0] w12;
  ...
```

**System Verilog** relaxed this rule and it should work in that language as is.